# decresing sequence implies $\lim{n u_n} $ exists?

Tags: sequences-and-series

if $(u_n)$ is a nonincreasing sequence of positive real
numbers; how to prove or disprove  that the sequence $(nu_n)$ admits a limit?
We know  two results

1- if $(u_n)$ is a  sequence of positive real
numbers such that $\sum_n a_n$ converges, and if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n u_n$ exists, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n u_n = 0$

2- if $(u_n)$ is a nonincreasing sequence of positive real
numbers such that $\sum_n u_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n u_n = 0$.

**PS :  I corrected the usual notation for a sequence**

Comment: $u_n=1/\sqrt n$, or even $u_n=1$?

Comment: You give examples where $n u_n$ admits a limit.

Comment: Why do you mix notations like that? The usual notation for a sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ is $(a_n)$; the notation $\{a_n\}$ (if it means anything) means the _set_ $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: @TonyK Oddly, $\{a_n\}$ is also a common notation for sequences (why? it beats me). But I also think is a very bad idea to mix both notations.

Comment: @jjagmath: I would argue that using curly braces is mathematically illiterate. Curly braces are for sets, as any fule kno.

Comment: @TonyK John Milnor uses that notation. Are you calling John Milnor "mathematically illiterate"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kenta S gave two valid examples in their comment: both $u_n = \frac1{\sqrt n}$ and $u_n=1$ have the property that $\lim_{n\to\infty} nu_n = \infty$. It's important to note that, despite the use of the equals sign in that notation, it indicates a specific way that $\lim_{n\to\infty} nu_n$ fails to exist. (Infinity is not a number.)

But other divergent behaviour is also possible. Consider for example
$$
u_n = 2^{-\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} = \min\bigg\{ \frac1{2^k}\colon \frac1{2^k} > \frac1n \bigg\},
$$
so that $(u_n) = (1,\frac12,\frac12,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac18,\dots)$. It's not hard to show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} nu_n = 2$ but $\liminf_{n\to\infty} nu_n = 1$, and so $\lim_{n\to\infty} nu_n$ does not exist.

Comment: Greg Martin Thank you for ur counter example

Answer (score -1):

Let $y_n = n u_n$. Then $L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n$ exists iff $\forall \varepsilon \exists m_0 \forall m \geq m_0 \mbox{ s.t. }|y_m - L| < \varepsilon$, i.e. for any small value, the $y_n$ beyond some point are all closer to $L$ than that value.

This means that $|n u_n - L| < \varepsilon$, so $|u_n - \frac{L}{n}| < \frac{\varepsilon}{n}$, or to rearrange it (and taking advantage of the fact that $u_n > 0$), $\frac{L - \varepsilon}{n} < u_n < \frac{L + \varepsilon}{n}$.

This means that the limit can only exist if $u_n = o(n^{-1})$ , i.e. $u_n$ shrinks faster than $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: The conclusion is not correct: take $u_n = \frac1n$ for example.

Comment: You're right, I think I meant to say u_n = O(1/n), so it shrinks at least as fast as 1/n but not necessarily faster.